# Adding Columns in Loop to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling to understand the behaviour of Python's Pandas library when adding columns in a loop to a dataframe. I want to loop through a list of objects (these are actually tuples of dates) adding a number of columns in each loop. A simplified version of this is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3), columns=('a', 'b', 'c'))

for x in range(10):

    # Printed on each loop:
    print('Adding column type 1')
    df['{}_type1'.format(x)] = 'Type 1'

    # Printed on last loop only:
    print('Adding column type 2')
    df['{}_type2'.format(x)] = 'Type 2'
```

I would expect this to add 20 new columns to the dataframe (2 per loop), but instead it adds 11 columns; the first 10 of 'Type 1', and the 11th of 'Type 2'. Further, the first print is outputted 10 times but the second only once:

```
Adding column type 1
Adding column type 1
Adding column type 1
Adding column type 1
Adding column type 1
Adding column type 1
Adding column type 1
Adding column type 1
Adding column type 1
Adding column type 1
Adding column type 2
```

I am new to Pandas so may be missing something fundamental but this seems like a bug to me, perhaps a rogue `continue` in the logic that does the vectorised operation? Any thoughts or explanations would be greatly welcomed.

Thanks,
Dominic

Comment: Your code works for me, are you sure you don't have some indentation problem?

Comment: Thanks for coming back so quickly. You're right - I have tried running this as a script and it worked. I should have mentioned that I am running this in iPython, which must be what's causing the issue.

Comment: I ran your code in ipython and it works fine, is there some copy and paste problem. Also what is it you want to achieve here

Comment: A bit more testing shows that I get the above output pasting from the clipboard by right-clicking, but using the magic %paste function I have no such problem. Lesson learnt. In short I'm trying to do some analysis of company turnover by financial period, so the columns I'm adding are headcount and leaver counts based on dates in other columns. I'm certain there's a better way to approach this but it is as much a learning exercise as anything else. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in fact an issue with Pandas. The above scenario was created by pasting the code into iPython by right-clicking. Using the %paste magic function (as the documentation recommends) does not produce this issue.